# Make section on top of all div

Tags: css

I am trying to make the Country list from drop down to be on top of the page. It going behnid the content.

I did changed the section itself with home page.

It working now.

Comment: [z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)?

Comment: could you share the code with us ? how to help you

Comment: @Hash I have shared the URL, I tried make the changes by inspecting the page elements but the section is not coming on top.

Comment: @Swellar, I did tried z-index but still the element doesn't come on top of divs.

Comment: @DeepakKumar We need the code for that specific part, not the URL of the site

Comment: can you provide the details of what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have given overflow: hidden to .header-inner because of which the list is getting hidden. Once you remove it the image will overflow. So following is the solution for both issues:

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay bg-opacity-5">
  <img src="images/header-img_howitworks.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive-1">
</div>
```

You need to move the image inside the overlay div.

CSS:

```
.header-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px !important;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    z-index: 0;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}
.header-inner.two .overlay {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

In CSS, remove overflow hidden from .header-inner and add it to the overlay.

Comment: It's not working for me. I only require the dropdown to be on the top.

Comment: Similar to the one on the home page.

Comment: You have not even tried what I have sent to you.. Please add my code for me to debug it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you give `overflow:hidden` in **.header-inner** class that is issue if you remove that property then dropdown become proper

Comment: I can't remove that property